# Redirect to Strava Oauth page does not work in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, strava

I want to integrate my Laravel application with Strava. I have created a model called `StravaModel` with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class StravaModel extends Model
{
    private $client_id;
    private $client_secret;
    private $redirect_uri;
    private $client;
    private $strava_uri = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client_id = env('CT_STRAVA_CLIENT_ID', ''); # Strava Client ID
        $this->client_secret = env('CT_STRAVA_SECRET_ID', ''); # Strava Secrect
        $this->redirect_uri = env('CT_STRAVA_REDIRECT_URI', ''); # Strava Redirect URi
        $this->client = new Client();

    }

    public function connectStrava()
    {
        return redirect($this->returnStravaUrl());
    }

    public function returnStravaUrl()
    {
        return('https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='. $this->client_id .'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='. $this->redirect_uri . '&scope=read_all,profile:read_all,activity:read_all&state=strava'); 
    }
}
```

In my controller, I do the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\StravaModel;

class StravaController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
      $stravaModel = new StravaModel();
      $stravaModel->connectStrava();
    }
}
```

My route file looks as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;    
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function() {
    Route::get('/strava', 'StravaController@index')->name('strava');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

However I just get a blank screen, why doesn't the page redirect to the strava oath?

Comment: maybe have a look at this package: RichieMcMullen/laravel-strava

Comment: The code I created is entirely based on that package. To be clear, also when I just use that package (using composer...), it does not redirect.